# Do I need NVRAM/SMC reset to restore a used MacBook Air to defaults?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, power-management, nvram

I've bought a used MacBook Air (Mid 2013) running Yosemite and I'd like to restore every setting to defaults, as in, start over with a fresh clean OS.

What are the things I have to run to make sure the system is good conditions before performing a reinstall?

Should I reset NVRAM and SMC to set stuff like volume and mouse speed to default, or a OS reinstall via recovery will take care of that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erasing a hard drive with Recovery HD (or better - a flash drive) will remove everything. You don't need to do a NVRAM/SMC reset (you can if you'd like)

Comment: Nvram contains information about connected BT and WLAN devices, doesnt it?

Comment: "The settings that are stored in NVRAM depend on the type of Mac you're using, and the types of devices connected to it." - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063